# Intel UHD Grapics issue on Protectli VP4650?

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have a Protectli VP4650. Im having issues with the graphics. Moving windows around casues major bluring and flickering text. Specs say it has "Intel UHD Graphics for 10th Gen".

Can someone verify if its using the correct drivers, looks like it is. Otherwise would this issue be caused by using X11 instead of Wayland? I have to use X11 because I use Synergy and it doesn't support Wayland yet.

Samsung Odyssey G5 via disp-port
2560 x 1440 (16:9)
165.00 Hz
100% Scale

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bac (rev 05)
DeviceName: Onboard - Video
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2212
Kernel driver in use: i915

Linux 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Intel UHD graphics are integrated into CPU firmware and the Kernel, there are no special drivers.  What *exactly* are you having issues with when it comes to the drivers?  I would also *not* use a Protectli VP4650 for anything intense, those are designed to be more headless systems than mini-pc with a GUI that can really do anything.  (Protectli devices are better for headless like servers, rather than GUI driven from my experience)

Comment: thank you for reply.As stated, Moving cursor and windows around, its bluring a lot. It should work fine being an i5 with 32gb ram and 1tb drive. I dont do much with it other than fiddle around with Linux, learning, and web browsing. I dont have any other issues that i know of.